# Mandar datos de un txt a Java

Tags: java, netbeans

Bien, mi problema es el siguiente.

Mi programa tiene que leer los datos desde un .txt y sacar el promedio y clasificarlos.

Logre hacerlo pero ingresando directamente los numeros desde el codigo Ejemp
int edad[]={3,12,1,20,52,10,3,20,99,12,52,4,43,20,99};

Y hasta abajo logre que imprimiera mis datos de txt, el problema es que yo quiero que los datos que ingrese en el txt sean los que el programa lea para sacar el promedio y clasifacarlos, osea que así como mi programa lee Int y lo que escribi, así quiero que lea desde mi txt.

```
package edades01;
// Ramirez Nava Diego Isair 2S1
import java.io.*;
public class Edades01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int edad[]={3,12,1,20,52,10,3,20,99,12,52,4,43,20,99};
        Edades01.Mostrar(edad); 
        Edades01 a=new Edades01();//crear un objeto de la clase edad01
        a.promedioedad();

        //lee el archivo edadestxt

        System.out.println(a.edadestxt("C:\\Archivos P\\JavaApplication\\edades.txt"));

    }
    static int niños=0;
    static int adolescentes=0;
    static int adultos=0;
    static int adultosmayores=0;
    static double promedioNiños=0;
    static double promedioAdolescentes;
    static double promedioAdultos;
    static double promedioMayores;

    public static void Mostrar(int edad[]){

        for(int a=0;a<edad.length;a++){
            System.out.print("\n"+edad[a]+"\n");
            if(edad[a]<11){
                niños++;
                promedioNiños+=edad[a];
            }
            if(edad[a]>=12 && edad[a]<=17){
                adolescentes++;
                promedioAdolescentes+=edad[a];
            }
            if(edad[a]>=18 && edad[a]<=59){
                adultos++;
                promedioAdultos+=edad[a];
            }
            if(edad[a]>60 && edad[a]<105){
                adultosmayores++;
                promedioMayores+=edad[a];
            }
       }

       System.out.print("Poblacion: "+edad.length);
       System.out.print("niños: "+niños+"\n");
       System.out.print("adolescentes: "+adolescentes+"\n");
       System.out.print("adultos: "+adultos+"\n");
       System.out.print("adultos mayores: "+adultosmayores+"\n");
   }

   public void promedioedad(){
       System.out.println("promedio niños es: "+(promedioNiños / niños ));
       System.out.println("promedio niños es: "+(promedioAdolescentes / 
adolescentes ));
       System.out.println("promedio niños es: "+(promedioAdultos / adultos ));
       System.out.println("promedio niños es: "+(promedioMayores / adultosmayores 
)); 
    }

                //LECTURA DE TEXTO PLANO CON METODO TRY Y CATCH
    public String edadestxt(String direccion){ //mandar a llamar la direccion 
del archivo

        String texto="";

        try{
            BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(direccion)); // se crea 
el objeto y mandar a llamar la direcion con filereader
            String temp="";
            String bfRead;

            System.out.println("*****//LECTURA DE TEXTO EDADES.TXT//*****");

            while((bfRead = bf.readLine())!=null){ //realiza ciclo mientras bfRead tiene datos
                temp = temp +bfRead+"\n"; //guarda el texto del archivo

            }
            texto=temp;
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println("El archivo no existe");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return texto; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Cual es tu problema?

Comment: ¿Que formato tiene el fichero?

Comment: Creo recordar que tenías que serializar el array para poder meterlo al fichero, en cualquier caso, guarda los números directamente al fichero ( int ) y cuando los saques, guardalos en un array, obtendrías el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1):

voy a dar por supuesto que el fichero tiene una única línea y el formato es valor,valor,valor... (Ejemplo: 3,12,1,20,52,10,3,20,99,12,52,4,43,20,99)

```
public int[] leerFichero(String pathFichero) {
        //Inicializamos el array que devolveremos
        int[] array;

        //Leemos la linea del fichero
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String text = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(pathFichero)));
            text = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("La lectura del fichero ha fallado.");
        }finally {
            try{
                br.close();
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        //Convertimos ese texto en el array de int que manejaremos
        String[] elementos = text.split(",");
        array = new int[elementos.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(elementos[i]);
        }

        return array;
    }
```

No he puesto ningún tipo de control de errores por si el fichero no existe, tiene otros formatos, o se encuentra un carácter distinto a números, por lo que te invito a que investigues y eso se lo añadas dependiendo de tus necesidades y ayudandote a comprender mejor el código, como también podrías probar a trastear un poco con otros formatos del fichero y a informarte un poco mas sobre persistencia de datos, ya que es algo básico en programación.